# How to assign a relationship in Ember Data when it doesn't have an ID yet?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a new team member, which belongs in a team but the member doesn’t have an ID yet because the record hasn't been send to the server yet how do I tell the team that the member belongs in the team and let it appear in the team list before sending the team member to the server and assigning a unique ID to the member.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to just send the record back to the server, _before_ creating the relationship in your ember-data store. Surely only once you have _successfully_ added the new relationship on the backend should your front end create that relationship.

Comment: Just for being able to use the app offline. And also for speed.For example if i send a message the message would be already shown in the conversation it belongs to. Even if the client could not connect to the server for a few minutes it would then be automatically synced to the server later.

Comment: It should be easy to set the relationship one way. Because taking the team example: The ID of the team is known so assigning the member to the team is easy but I can't set the relationship the other way and thus my team member is not shown in the team list without a server connection.

Comment: This is what I found on my research: https://teamgaslight.com/blog/client-side-ids-with-ember-data

Comment: http://thau.me/2015/01/using-uuids-with-ember-data/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ember is geared towards saving the record to the back end, and then on the success callback creating your relationship and save it again. This ensures that ember-data remains a *slave* to the backend, ensuring data integrity.

You could look at [creating an ID in ember](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_generateIdForRecord), but this certainly sounds like *here be dragons* as you would need to purge your ember-data store and and get the real records and ID's from the server.

This process could be simplified by placing a flag on your model to say that it has a generated ID, but as I said *here be dragons*.

The safest option is to either just establish relationships once a record has been saved to the back end, or if offline is a real concern, you could use something like [Ember Pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/ember-pouch) to keep a synced local copy of your datastore, this will make the whole issue of resolving ID's a little more consistent.

Finally you could look into some sort of localStorage *man in the middle* to sync with your db, it has been discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457854/ember-data-sync-localstoragerestrealtimeonline-offline).